# How to read data from Leica DISTO via bluetooth?

Tags: c#, bluetooth

I have a Leica DISTO D3a BT. 
It is a measuring device and it send the measure via bluetooth.

I wrote some code to get the bluetooth stream, I receive the data but I always got the "Error 240" message.

It means (from the user manual) that I do not confirm the succesfulness of the data transmission.

How can I do it?

Here is my code:

```
int bytesRead = 0;
System.IO.Stream stream = client_.GetStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[k_BUFFER_BYTES];  
while(true)
{
    Task.Delay(100);
    if (client_.Available > 0) // Available contains the available bytes
    {
        int counter = 0;
        string output = "";

        while (counter < client_.Available)
        {
            bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, k_BUFFER_BYTES);
            counter += bytesRead ;

            output += System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        stream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n"), 0, 2);
        stream.Flush();

        Console.WriteLine(output + " - " + counter + " - " + client_.Available);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I got the answer! 
I installed a serial port sniffer and found that the acknowledge string to respond is:

**cfm\n**

So the code is now:

```
await stream.WriteAsync(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("cfm\n"), 0, 4);   
await stream.FlushAsync();
```

[image]

PS: I would like to thanks a lot the Leica customer care to **not** answer my mails and phone calls.

Comment: Send "cfb 0\r\n" to permanently turn the E240 off; or "cfb 128\r\n" to turn it back on again. "This command is only valid for BT 2.1 devices but not for the BT 4.0".

Answer (score 1):

Use [Disto Transfer PC](http://lasers.leica-geosystems.com/leica-disto-app-directory/leica-distotm-transfer-software-bluetoothr-21-or-40-microsoft-windowsr-os) application to turn off the acknowledged signal(E240)

(You need to maximize the application to see it's extra features)

Answer (score 0):

Try sending <kbd>CR</kbd><kbd>LF</kbd> on the stream. Flushing it afterwards.

I've checked this out here: https://www.b4x.com/android/forum/threads/connect-leica-disto-via-bluetooth-spp.53104/

although the language is different, the concept should be the same.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Octanic, I added these two lines:  `stream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n"), 0, 2); stream.Flush();` but it didn't solved the problem! Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: @Michele It seems correct. But, you could consider the stream is not accepting ASCII encoding. Have you tried another encoding, like UTF-8? Apart from the error, does the stream have any extra data? I mean, do you get any other information along with the error?

Comment: If I use UTF-8 encoding the bytes are the same two (13, 10). If I use Unicode the bytes are four (13,0,10,0) instead of two and I receive the @E203 answer. But it doesn't solve my problem unfortunally